# how to make a generated table scale to a div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to scale a js generated table to a div's height and width. I've tried some solutions online but none worked for me. (the table is x*x
depends on user input)

so far I've only mannaged to scale the table on width but not the height.

this is what I did:

```css
div
{
    max-width: 70vw;
    max-height: 90vh;   
    overflow-x: auto;
}
td {
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #d5bbee;
}
table{
   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    border-radius: 20px; 
    border-spacing: 15px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    background-color:rgb(102, 184, 211) ;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

the width of every cell is somehow scaled to fit the width of the table, but the height of every cell is still 200px so it acts diffrently. Iv'e tried `table-layout:fixed` and `overflow:hidden` but nothing have the same affect on the height.
I do want the table to only scale if it's going to become larger than the div.

thanks for any help :]

Comment: You should probably try formatting the table rows

Comment: I don't know what to try, I've played abit with them too :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set parent div height.  Currently, it will expend only if necessary.

```css
div
{
    max-width: 70vw;
    max-height: 90vh;
    height: 90vh; 
    overflow-x: auto;
}
td {
    
    width: 200px;
    
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #d5bbee;
}
table{
   
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    
    border-radius: 20px; 
    border-spacing: 15px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    background-color:rgb(102, 184, 211) ;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this works well! but now I face another issue - when trying to put any content inside the table it is instantly makes the tr height diffrent, i don't know why, but for example if you add any text/image, its ok size, but the td height grows like 3 times in size and the rest of the trs shrink... the issue seem to be with the table height size...